# Spring WS - How to read a servlet init-param in an @Endpoint class?

Tags: spring, spring-ws

I have a Spring WS class annotated with `@Endpoint`. I need to read a custom servlet init param from `web.xml` as follows. What is the best way to read this parameter from within this class?

`<context-param>
        <param-name>myparam</param-name>
        <param-value>myvalue</param-value>
    </context-param>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe @Endpoint annotated class is managed by spring container if so , then you can Autowire ServletContext as below

```
class MyWS{

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private ServletContext servletContext;


    public String myParamTest() {

        String ret = servletContext.getInitParameter("myparam");
        LOG.debug(ret);
        return ret;
    }
}
```